# Excel error 1004, Highlight adjecent cells gray when yes

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

I'm trying to put a macro where I select `Yes` in a row, the next cells are grayed out. So I have got couple of yes columns, but for the life of me can't figure/fix out the error

> **Error**
>    Runtime Error 1004
>    Application-defined or object-defied error

**Code**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If ActiveCell.Column = 5 Then

    Set r = Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1), ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7))

    If Target.Value = "Yes" Or Target.Value = "YES" Then
        r.Interior.Color = RGB(192, 192, 192)
    Else
        r.Interior.Color = xlNone
    End If
End If

 If ActiveCell.Column = 7 Then

    Set s = Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1), ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3))

    If Target.Value = "Yes" Or Target.Value = "YES" Then
        s.Interior.Color = RGB(192, 192, 192)
    Else
        s.Interior.Color = xlNone
    End If
 End If
End Sub
```

[image: 1]

Comment: [Worth A Read](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860894/ms-excel-crashes-when-vba-code-runs/13861640#13861640)

Comment: Thanks for that Siddharth, That helped allot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing *ActiveCell* to *Target* is a good start. You should also compensate for more than a single target cell in case a block of values is pasted into a range overlapping columns E and/or G.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Union(Columns(5), Columns(7))) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo Fìn
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Dim o As Range, t As Range
        For Each t In Intersect(Target, Union(Columns(5), Columns(7)))
            Select Case t.Column
                Case 5
                    Set o = t.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 7)
                Case 7
                    Set o = t.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 3)
            End Select
            If LCase(t.Value) = "yes" Then
                o.Interior.Color = RGB(192, 192, 192)
            Else
                o.Interior.Pattern = xlNone
            End If
        Next t
    End If

Fìn:
    Set o = Nothing
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

I've only set the range of the cells to receive the fill color first. Note that there does seem to be a crossover logic issue where if E5 receives a *Yes* and G5 receives a *No* then only K5:L5 will be grey. I made the comparison to *yes* non-case-sensitive.

Errors are covered by a safe exit.

Comment: Thanks for the code, and i didn't know about the error exit so now i know

Answer (score 1):

`ActiveCell` is not the cell that changed.  `Target` is.  You need to replace all of the references to `ActiveCell` to `Target` and adjust the offsets accordingly.

Comment: Hi, changed them to `target`, but i still get the same error

Comment: Did you change all *6* ActiveCell to Target?

Comment: Changed all of them, found the issue though, it was using conditional highlighting so that's what was conflicting with the macro

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue though, it was using conditional highlighting so that's what was conflicting with the macro